# Причины тревоги всегда по разному расположены

Tags: поддержка, тревоги

У меня очень неоднозначное отношение к определённой категории вопросов новичков, мнение пока не сформулировала, в процессе. Поэтому иногда отвечаю, иногда ставлю тревогу, иногда отвечаю и ставлю тревогу, иногда пролистываю. По ситуации.

И проблема, когда часто ставишь тревоги, что вроде запоминаешь, какие бывают причины и как они расположены. И в какой-то момент, видя вопрос, уже понимаешь, какая тут нужна причина, а когда нажимаешь на тревогу, там причины расположены незнакомо, и ту самую найти не можешь. Но иногда, если поискать, она всё-таки находишь. А иногда нет.

Отчего это зависит? Как расположены причины и есть ли нужная.

На примерах во втором варианте отсутствует удалить из-за проблем с качеством.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Никогда не замечал смены расположения причин, можно скриншоты?

Comment: Буду скринить, как ещё раз встречу, прикреплю

Comment: Возможно, вы иногда нажимаете на "закрыть", а иногда на "тревога".

Comment: @Эникейщик Вроде бы кнопка "Закрыть" появляется только после 3к репутации.

Comment: Да, кнопки закрыть у меня нет

Comment: @andreymal Я прикрепила два скрина. Во втором нет "удалить из-за проблем с качеством". Как я заметила, этого пункта может не быть, если дан ответ, но не всегда (там ещё какие-то условия должны быть). Конкретно у меня была проблема, что хотела поставить "Непонятна суть вопроса", но "Необходимо улучшить" не было.

Comment: Действительно, у меня тоже пропадает. Судя по моим экспериментам — он пропадает на вопросах, которые старше недели (видимо, движок подразумевает, что если за неделю вопрос никто не удалил, то значит он нормальный)

Comment: А вот «Необходимо улучшить» у меня есть вроде бы везде (хотя, возможно, это связано с тем, что у меня есть 3к репутации и мне доступно закрытие)

Comment: @andreymal У меня у закрытых только спам, невежливо и нужен модератор, но это логично. Там точно был незакрытый вопрос. Но воспроизвести пока не получилось - сейчас вроде у всех незакрытых это есть.

Comment: @andreymal Либо там было "Необходимо улучшить", но не было "Непонятна суть вопроса", могу путать. У меня "Непонятна суть вопроса" поставить не получилось тогда.

Comment: @EOF а, ок. Я в описании кнопки не нашел.